# What happen when we use updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

This is very basic question but still not solve from my end. I got a nice link [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx). and come to know there are so many overheads while using update panel. Instead of that use page method. My question pointers are as below.

1. Which data send to the server in ajax call (I mean whole page data or only update panel data)?
2. What portion get refreshed at client side.
3. Why page does not flickered or how browser only repaint the updatepanel portion.

I am expecting only the theoretical answers to clear the concept.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is very useful. But it does not answer my question fully.

Comment: Also look at [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/07/13/113913.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:

1. *All* input fields on the aspx page will be submitted along
   with the *whole* `ViewState` (and few more hidden fields). You can see what is being
   transferred by pressing F12 (in chrome, or in firefox if firebug is
   installed) and selecting the *network* tab.
2. All controls *inside* the updatepanel along with the `ViewState` will be
   updated/refreshed.
3. The request is asynchronous. Response will be captured by the
   javascript (plugged in via `ScriptManager`) and it will modify the
   DOM structure (of associating updatepanel portion) to reflect the
   update; so you will not see the *loading* icon on the browser tab.